# Prove if $\int ^1_0 [3-f(x)]\,dx=0$ then $g(x)=3e^{-x^2}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)=e^{x^2}g(x)$ and $g(x)$ is continuous is  such that $f(x) \le 3,$ prove that if $\int ^1_0 [3-f(x)]\,dx=0$  then $g(x)=3e^{-x^2}$ on $[0,1].$

Since $\int ^1_0 [3-f(x)]\,dx=0 \implies \int ^1_0 3\, dx=\int ^1_0 f(x)\,dx\\
3=\int ^1_0 f(x)\,dx=\int ^1_0e^{x^2}g(x)\,dx.$
What is the next step?

Answer (score 1):

Since $3-f(x)$ is continuous and positive, it's integral on $[0,1]$ is $0$ if and only if $3-f(x)$ is $0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. You can prove it simply as that:

If $3-f(x_0)>0$ for some point $x_0$, then by continuity there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ it is $3-f(x)>\frac{3-f(x_0)}{2}$. By integrating, one has $\int_0^1(3-f(x))dx\geq\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\frac{3-f(x_0)}{2}dx=(3-f(x_0))\delta>0$, a contradiction.

Since $f$ is constantly $3$, $g(x)=3e^{-x^2}$.